# UIViewController Destructor not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Currently I have two UIViewControllers called `FormA` and `FormB`

Now `FormA` calls `FormB` as such (formB property in formA is nonatomic and strong)

```
self.formB = [[ MediaPlayer alloc] initWithNibName:@"MediaPlayer" bundle:nil ];
//Pass some values to FormB (all of these fields are strong)
((formB*)self.formB).SongInProgress_Name= songName;
((formB*)self.formB).SongInProgress_Path= song_path;
((formB*)self.formB).MusicCollectionPath= self.ArraySongNamePath;
[self presentViewController:self.formB animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

and when FormB attempts to close it goes back to FormA as such

```
[ ((FormA*)self.presentingViewController) BackHere];
```

Now Back in FormA. FormA attempts to close FormB in this way

```
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil];

self.formB = nil;
```

Doing the above does not call the destructor in FormB which is

```
-(void)dealloc {

    /* Desructor*/
}
```

Why si the destructor not being called ?

Comment: Does `FormB` have a `strong` reference to `FormA`, and more importantly, does anything else have a `strong` reference to `FormB`?

Comment: I am not aware of any other portion of the code that has a strong reference to this. I am reading on profiling hopefully that might help.

Comment: Dont really know why the downvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not be the source of the problem, but you should *never* do this:

```
self.formB = [[ MediaPlayer alloc] initWithNibName:@"MediaPlayer" bundle:nil ];
```

It is not your business to retain a strong reference to a view controller that is to be presented. The view hierarchy is going to retain it. You are not the owner; the view hierarchy is. So you must not take ownership. Make this a *local* variable when you create and present the view controller:

```
MediaPlayer* mp = [[ MediaPlayer alloc] initWithNibName:@"MediaPlayer" bundle:nil ];
mp.SongInProgress_Name = songName; // etc.
[self presentViewController:mp animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

Now, as I said at the start, that is important but it might not be the source of the problem. You may have a retain cycle *inside* your implementation of MediaPlayer. But you didn't show any of that code, so I have no way of knowing. Why not use Instruments and the Leaks template to find out where the retain cycle is?

Comment: Thanks for the tip I will update my code. Also I updated my post. I am passing some strong references to FormB from FormA do you think they might be the reason formB does not destruct ?

Comment: Not at all (at least so far as you have shown the additional code). But I have no way of knowing what else you are doing. I repeat - you do not have to wonder, you do not have to ask. Instruments will _tell_ you where the problem is.

Comment: Any suggestions on what I should be looking at in instruments. Which section in particular ?

Comment: Just thought I would post an update. The issue was of another class having a strong delegate type . The strong delegate type kept the class alive.

Comment: I knew it was somewhere else! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it- I am still trying to acclimate to XCODE

Comment: I'd say if you figured this one out you are doing pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Complementary to Matt's answer, it's is very likely that your view controller is not deallocating due to a retain cycle. These are produced by objects that hold strong references to each other, which is common when you are not properly decoupling your view controllers, for example:

You can optimise your code by changing the line `[((FormA*)self.presentingViewController) BackHere];` to `[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`. This allows you for FormB to become a more abstract view controller that can be presented from other view controllers that are not FormA in the future, and removed the need to store FormB as a variable in FormA, increasing decoupling of the two classes and reducing the chance of you unintentionally creating a retain cycle.

Comment: I'm happy if you solved it, but I do not believe that changing from `[((FormA*)self.presentingViewController) BackHere];` to `[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` of itself would have the _slightest_ effect on your memory management.

Comment: Apparently it did (a tleast thats what I think). I am still not sure why. I am currently looking up resources on profiling and if I figure it out Ill post back. I am also using some external libraries that have ARC turned off so I am not sure what might be going on. Again Ill profile and report back on what the issue might be. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Matt, you are right, in an of itself doing that would not affect your memory management, my advise just proposed the use of good code practices in order to reduce the chance of unintentionally creating a retain cycle by eliminating the need to have a reference of the child object in a parent object, which seems to be what MistyD was experiencing. Cheers!